# Data sync in realtime database in firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Firebase gives the information that they support max 100 simultaneous connections in their free tier.

Question 1) Assume that I have a table in my database which app users see on their screens. And whenever I update the table, the change in the content is mirrored in the apps as well (on the mobile phone). Since the max simultaneous connections is set to 100, does that mean that the Firebase will only refresh the content (at the user side) for 100 users at a time?

Question 2) Does anyone know for how long the user stays in the connected state after interacting with the realtime database?

(There is unfortunately no code for this question but the problem is not related to a piece of code either.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, all connected users will see updates, up to the 100 max.
2. The duration of time connected is not affected by the limit.  It just refuses new clients from connected after the limit is exceeded.  You will see an error in the client app if that happens.

Comment: thank you for your answer. Is it so that that error message needs to be handled in the app so that users do not see the error while the app is syncing with the realtime database?

Comment: Do whatever you need to do in that case.  It's up to you to figure out what to show the user in case of an error.